# Diffusion Advection equation discretization scheme

Tags: reference-request, numerical-methods

I am looking for a good reference to understand the basic discretization schemes applied to the Stationary Diffusion Advection equation.
$$-\epsilon \frac{d^2u(x)}{dx^2}+\beta \frac{du(x)}{dx}=0$$
Especially for the Upwind and the Scharfetter-Gummel schemes.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just from looking at your equation, I would guess that you can use just about any basic discretization scheme. Schemes like Upwind and Scharfetter-Gummel (I had to look up this last one) were developed to handle partial differential equations that include dependence on time, which can introduce all sorts of numerical headaches.

If you need a general guide on numerical methods for ODE's, there are a number of books that would work. If you want free and instant information, I'd recommend [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_ordinary_differential_equations#Methods) Wikipedia article. It discusses three basic schemes in detail and then suggests further reading for more advanced methods.

If you are already comfortable with this introductory material and are looking for a more accurate scheme, I would personally use one of the Runge-Kutta methods, probably the popular 4th order one because it is the one with which I am most comfortable. These methods were developed to solve first-order equations and so you need to do it twice (once on $u'$ and again on $u''$). Some Mathematica code to do exactly this, which you can use as pseudocode if you are using some other software / language, can be found [here](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081119015413AANHSSI).

If you want to know about Upwind, I think the Wikipedia [article](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081119015413AANHSSI) on this is quite usable. [Here](https://www.utdallas.edu/~frensley/minitech/ScharfGum.pdf) is a pdf on Sharfetter-Gummel. I want to emphasize again that I am pretty sure these methods are for partial differential equations. At the very least, their general descriptions in these sources are formulated at such. I do not know if they can be usefully translated to ODE methods (by 'useful' I mean without erasing their purpose).

Lastly, [this](http://www.nukleonika.pl/www/back/full/vol55_2010/v55n4p601f.pdf) is a publication presenting a numerical solution to a diffusion-advection system that appears a little more advanced than the preceding.

Comment: Thanks @EricKightley for the detailed reply. Actually, I mentionned these two discretization schemes simply because I started getting interested by the CFD, and so, I picked up a very simple available program that I understood most of it, except two lines regarding the discretization. \\ But still, I have to mention that you gave a good enough answer and I do thank you. I will look up the suggested articles and see if I can find what I am looking for. Cheers.

Comment: @user2536125: Are you coding any of these methods yourself, or are you using canned packages in some numerical software (e.g. Matlab)?

Comment: ....I am actually using a simple Matlab m-File that I downloaded from the internet. the application is very simple, since the code contains only simple for loops and Matrx inversion.

Comment: @user2536125 I myself am still a beginner at doing this kind of thing. I took a class last year on numerical methods in Matlab. We wrote solvers (from scratch) to solve most simple combinations of reaction/diffusion equations, including some coupled ones. If there is any specific method you are struggling to implement and you want a working version let me know and I can check if I have one, or if you need some Matlab code looked at. Numerics folks gotta represent on the forums more!

Comment: ...Thanks again for the reply. Just as you said, numerics folks gotta represent on the forums more! Since you mentionned, It will be very helpfull if you have the course script with the developed codes. I don't have any specefic ideas about the methods, but, I just aim at understanding the structure of the code, discretization, grids and optimization.